# Making a responsive grid of cards in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, responsive, css-grid, card

I'm trying to create a responsive grid with cards in Vuetify. Every card must be the same size but if I add a long text under it (second card), the card is always the max size (I also make this with [breakpoints](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/) but Vuetify only has 5 breakpoints and I would need it more. I could add a custom breakpoint for every column but that is a bit ugly solution).

Also last row must be aligned to the left like in the sketch below. I tried a lot of things but I want to use min-width and max-width so the gap between the cards would, in most cases, be the same. It should look something like this:

[image: Preview - grid of cards]

Here is my [codepen](https://rb.gy/f6n7d2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those card that have text too long won't resize becaues they don't recognize the parent width so the card width then just become maximum value. I fixed this by giving him absolute value and with some css I fixed it. Alignment at the end I fixed by just adding blank transparent cards so they are alignet correctly. Here is the solution in the [codepen](https://rb.gy/whrf0c)